# Excel VBA- Split Cell Strings into individual cells and copy cells to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel, split

I am trying to split  cell strings into various cells in one Excel spread sheet and then copy and paste the split cells with new headings into a new sheet. Below is the image of what I am trying to split.

[What I am trying to split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMOr5.png)

Here is what I am trying to achieve.
[Wanted Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXbJB.png).

Unfortunately I am new to stackoverflow so my images wont show. If users do not wish to click the link I will try explain by other means:

I have various cells which contain long strings which I am trying to split.
Below is an example of two rows which I would like to split.

```
  Setup      |  MC 1: 1 x 18 , MC 2: 2 x 23 , MC 3: 2 x 32|
 ------------|----------------------------------------------
  Microphone |  2 x PHILIP DYNAMI SBMCMD                  |
```

(where | represents a column break)

I would like to split the above with the following headers as shown below.

```
 Setup     |       |Speaker|Tables|People|Speaker|Tables|People|Speaker|Tables|People| 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |       | MC1   |  1   |  18  | MC2   | 2    | 23   | MC3   | 2    | 32   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |       |       |      |      |       |      |      |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microphone |       |Number |Manufc| Model|MdlNum |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |       |  2    |PHILIP|DYNAMI|SBMCMD |
```

The following code works for the setup rows. However it does not work for the microphone rows. It manages to split the correct delimiter, however it does not target the correct row containing the Microphone data.

```
    Sub Sample()

Dim MYAr, setup
Dim MicAr, Mic
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long, col As Long, Rrow As Long

Dim arrHeaders
Dim arrayHeadersMic


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
'Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add '~~> Add a new worksheet for output
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
rw = 2 '<< output starts on this row
arrHeaders = Array("Speaker", "Tables", "People")
arrHeadersMic = Array("Number", "Manufacturer", "Model", "Model Number")

With ws
    Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '~~> get the last row
    For i = 1 To Lrow
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Setup" Then

            wsOutput.Cells(rw, 1).Value = "Setup"
           wsOutput.Cells(rw + 3, 1).Value = "Microphone"

            setup = .Range("B" & i).Value
            If Len(setup) > 0 Then 'Len Returns an integer containing either the number of characters in a string or the nominal number of bytes required to store a variable.

                MYAr = SetupToArray(setup)
                'add the headers
                wsOutput.Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, 3).Value = arrHeaders
                wsOutput.Cells(rw + 3, 3).Resize(1, 4).Value = arrHeadersMic

                'fill headers across
                wsOutput.Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, 3).AutoFill _
                   Destination:=wsOutput.Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, UBound(MYAr) + 1)
                'populate the array
                wsOutput.Cells(rw + 1, 3).Resize(1, UBound(MYAr) + 1).Value = MYAr

                'figure out the microphone values here....

              Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


                If .Cells(5, 1).Value = "Microphone" Then



                    setup = 0
                    Mic = .Range("B" & i).Value
                    'If Len(Mic) > 0 Then

                    MicAr = MicToArray(Mic)

                        'fill headers across
                        wsOutput.Cells(rw + 3, 3).Resize(1, 4).AutoFill _
                        Destination:=wsOutput.Cells(rw + 3, 3).Resize(1, UBound(MicAr) + 1) 'UBound Returns the highest available subscript for the indicated dimension of an array.

                        'populate the array
                        wsOutput.Cells(rw + 4, 3).Resize(1, UBound(MicAr) + 1).Value = MicAr

                    'End If

               End If



                rw = rw + 7
            End If
        End If
    Next i


End With

End Sub

Function SetupToArray(v)
Dim MYAr, i
v = Replace(v, ":", ",")
v = Replace(v, " x ", ",")
MYAr = Split(v, ",")
'trim spaces...
For i = LBound(MYAr) To UBound(MYAr)
    MYAr(i) = Trim(MYAr(i))
Next i
SetupToArray = MYAr
End Function

Function MicToArray(w)
Dim MicAr, i
w = Replace(w, " x ", " ")
'w = Replace(w, " ", ",")
MicAr = Split(w, " ")



'trimspace
For i = LBound(MicAr) To UBound(MicAr)
    MicAr(i) = Trim(MicAr(i))
Next i
MicToArray = MicAr

End Function
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Screenshot shows pipe-delimited, but your sample text is comma-delimited: which is the actual delimiter?

Comment: Apologies @TimWilliams lets take it as the comma, I will change the screenshot

Comment: Simplest approach for the first one would be to replace all your various delimiters with a single type, then split on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: updated and tested - works for your "setup" data

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim MYAr, setup
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long, col As Long
    Dim arrHeaders


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add '~~> Add a new worksheet for output
    rw = 2 '<< output starts on this row
    arrHeaders = Array("Speaker", "Tables", "People")

    With ws
        Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '~~> get the last row
        For i = 1 To Lrow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Setup" Then

                wsOutput.Cells(rw, 1).Value = "Setup"
                wsOutput.Cells(rw + 1, 1).Value = "Microphone"

                setup = .Range("B" & i).Value
                If Len(setup) > 0 Then

                    MYAr = SetupToArray(setup)
                    'add the headers
                    wsOutput.Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, 3).Value = arrHeaders
                    'fill headers across
                    wsOutput.Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, 3).AutoFill _
                       Destination:=wsOutput.Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, UBound(MYAr) + 1)
                    'populate the array
                    wsOutput.Cells(rw + 1, 3).Resize(1, UBound(MYAr) + 1).Value = MYAr

                    'figure out the microphone values here....

                    rw = rw + 6
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

Function SetupToArray(v)
    Dim MYAr, i
    v = Replace(v, ":", ",")
    v = Replace(v, " x ", ",")
    MYAr = Split(v, ",")
    'trim spaces...
    For i = LBound(MYAr) To UBound(MYAr)
        MYAr(i) = Trim(MYAr(i))
    Next i
    SetupToArray = MYAr
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for that Tim. I have been trying to use your example but am having trouble implementing it with my current code. I have updated my code with the changes I have made but am getting a runtime error 1004:Application defined or object-defined error. 
This occured after I changed the following:
    'write array to sheet
    ws.output.Cells(rw, col).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr

Comment: That was a (now fixed) typo in my code `ws.output` >> `wsOutput`

Comment: Cheers Tim. I have made the change to my code and am now getting a Runtime error '1004': Application defined or object-defined error. I am still very new to VBA and am having trouble understanding what is wrong

Comment: If you have an error, it's best to state exactly *where* the error is...

Comment: I have found the error thanks Tim. I am now figuring out how to add in the microphone values. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi @Tim Williams, I am trying to use another function in order to deal with the space delimiter and "x" for the microphone part of my as shown in my code in my question( no success yet). Is this the way you would have approached the manner?

Comment: I would probably use `w = Replace(w, " x ", " ")` and then split on space.

Comment: Excellent. I have updated my code in my question. I've managed to get the MicToArray function to split the correct delimiters however it is not targeting the rows of data that contain the microphone data, it is targeting rows with the setup data. Any ideas of how to get my function  to target the rows with the microphone data?

Comment: Just follow the same pattern as for "setup", or if the mic data is always directly below the setup data then `mic = .Range("B" & i).Offset(1,0).Value`

Comment: When I add in the Mic = .Range("B" & i).Offset(1,0).Value I get run-time error 1004. My apologies for the mass amount of questions. Your help is very much appreciated and expanding my VBA knowledge greatly!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why I am getting an error using the Offset property

Comment: after the comment 'figure out microphone values here
would i need to put in another for loop using a different variable other than "i"?

Comment: If you can share (DropBox, GDrive, etc) a workbook containing actual sample data I will give you a basic working solution.

Comment: That would be great thank you! Here is one below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07kTPaMi6Jna0hnbEw2TDV1OVk/view

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Thank you. I will use your code to find out where I have been going wrong. Very VERY much appreciated

Comment: Hi @Tim Williams I have another question related to my original question, However this time it is in regards to the layout of what I am trying to copy, ie more "Microphones" and different headers for each room. 
Here is a sample document with what I would like my sample data in sheet 1 and with what I would like my data too look like in Sheet2.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07kTPaMi6JndDVJS01HbVVoTDg/view
Would you recommend that I open up a new question with what I have tried?

Comment: Yes - a new question would be better

Comment: Excellent-for any of those following this thread I have posted a new question here
http://stackoverflow.com/q/41685287/7282657

Answer (score 1):

Easier to copy the range to the Windows Clipboard and use the TSV Text format (not tested):

```
Sheet1.Cells.Copy ' copy the range

With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}") ' this is late bound MSForms.DataObject
    Dim s As String
    .GetFromClipboard                 ' get the formats from the Windows Clipboard
    s = .GetText                      ' get the "Text" format
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' magic
    s = Replace(s, "MC ", "MC")     ' "MC 1"    to "MC1"
    s = Replace(s, " x ", "|")      ' "1 x 18"  to "1|18"
    s = Replace(s, " , ", "|")      ' "18 , MC" to "18|MC"
    s = Replace(s, ": ", "|")       ' "MC1: 1"  to "MC1|1"
    s = Replace(s, " ", "|")        ' "2|PHILIP DYNAMI SBMCMD" to "2|PHILIP|DYNAMI|SBMCMD"

    ' "more magic"
    s = Replace(s, "Setup" & vbTab, "/Setup||Speaker|Tables|People|Speaker|Tables|People|Speaker|Tables|People/||")
    s = Replace(s, "Microphone" & vbTab, "/Microphone||Number|manufacturer|Model|Model Num/||")
    s = Replace(s, "|", vbTab)        ' cells are separated by tab
    s = Replace(s, "/", vbNewLine)    ' rows are separated by new line

    .SetText s
    .PutInClipboard
End With

Sheet2.PasteSpecial "Text"        ' or Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```